# Why the output of following code is 4 and not tuple (4,)?

Tags: python, tuples

Why the output of following code is **4** and not tuple **(4,)** ?

```
tup = (1, 2, 4, 8)
tup = tup[-2:-1]
tup = tup[-1]
print(tup)
```

output

```
4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you called `tup[-1]` you accessed a specific element at index `-1`. On the other hand, when you called `tup[-2:-1]` you **sliced** the tuple, resulting in a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting **one** element from a tuple, so it gives you that specific element (an `int`, in this case).